# python 3 - reading a file within zipped archive places 'b' character at start of each line

Tags: python, file, zip

In the code below, I always get a strange output that places **b** before every line. Just the letter b.

E.g. a sample output is like this:

```
[b'2017-06-01,15:19:57,']
```

The script itself is this:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('myarchive.zip','r') as myzip:
    with myzip.open('logs/logfile1.txt') as myfile:
        next(myfile)
        print(myfile.readlines())
```

The archive has a single folder in it called "logs" and inside logs there are several text files, each with lines below an empty first line (hence the `next(myfile)`

It places the **b** before the data, no matter which file I try to read. If there are multiple lines in a file it outputs something like this:

```
[b'2017-06-01,15:06:28,start session: \n', b'2017-06-01,15:06:36,stop session']
```

Why is it placing the pesky **b** there?

Comment: @zwer could you make this as answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python 3.x there is a distinction between strings and bytes data. When representing bytes as strings Python adds `b` prefix to denote that. If you want to treat your `bytes` as strings, you first need to decode them into a string:

```
your_string = your_bytes.decode("utf-8")
```

Of course, the codec you'll use depends on how your string was encoded into bytes in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Because zip is binary format and while reading from it it gives `bytes` instead of `str`.

you can convert using `str.decode()`

for example

```
>>>byte_string = b'2017-06-01,15:06:28,start session: \n'
>>>byte_string.decode()
2017-06-01,15:06:28,start session: \n
```

will give you the desired str.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, (from the documentation) bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater must be expressed with escapes.

This is just clarifying formatting in the print output.  If you want to output strings without this formatting, you can use a format string like this:

```
print("%s" % myfile.readlines())
```